# Why doesn't my image display in the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I can't find the reason why the image won't display in the grid I created

```
Image img = new Image();

img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\logo.bmp", UriKind.Relative));

img.Width = 50;
img.Height = 50;
img.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);

grid1.Children.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your image URI is an absolute path.

You should write

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\logo.bmp", UriKind.Absolute));
```

or better

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\logo.bmp"));
```